# merge two dictionaries by key and sum values

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I have dictA `{'1': 3, '3': 0, '2', 1}`

and dictB `{'2': 0, '1': 1, '3', 4}`

Both dictionaries will always be the same length, but the order of their key/value pairs may vary.

How do I merge `dictA` with `dictB` and sum the values according to the keys?

The output, from above, would be:

```
{'1': 4, '3', 4, '2', 1}
```

(order of the key/value pairs doesn't matter)

Comment: In Python 2, there's no such thing as "the order" of the keys and values.  Dictionaries do not remember that information.

Comment: @Kevin, Unless it's an `OrderedDict()`.

Comment: Thanks, I had searched but missed that post somehow.  It had what I needed.